Typescript not seeing showPicker method on HTMLSelectElement
I have this bit of code in react:
const selRef = useRef(0);
const getSelectElement = (): HTMLSelectElement => (selRef.current as unknown as HTMLSelectElement);

// futher down ...
const openSelect = () => getSelectElement().showPicker();

// further down more ...
return (<select ref={selRef}> ... </select>)

The code works. The showPicker() method opens up the select dropdown, as it should.
But Typescript keeps complaining that "Property 'showPicker' does not exist on type 'HTMLSelectElement'."
What's going on here?
I expect TypeScript to pass this code because instances of HTMLSelectElement do indeed have a showPicker() method.

The recent TypeScript DOM defs show that method should be present. Did you updated them in your project? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/be1f89271cf954d37a62edca0942bd08528abbb6/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L12527

It's hard to reply without a [mre]. For example, can you reproduce the error in the TypeScript Playground? Here's a template to help you get started: https://tsplay.dev/NroL5m
